# How to share a post multiple times in windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, windows-phone-8, fbconnect

I'm developing wp 8 application.

In my application I have Facebook share option.Every thing works correctly.

but problem is first time only post on wall option work . if i again click post on wall button post not working. it show me error In alert Box

**Error Occurred :The Remote Server returned an error: NotFound**

If i delete the already posted msg in fb wall.

Then I click again the post on wall it's work.

If msg is posted in wall then the code return above error msg in alert.

My Code For post on wall Button

```
private void BtnPostOnWall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookClient.Instance.PostMessageOnWall(TextToPost, new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(PostMessageOnWallCompleted));
    }

 void PostMessageOnWallCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
            return;
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred: " + e.Error.Message);
            return;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Result);

        string result = e.Result;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResponseData));
        ResponseData responseData = (ResponseData)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);

        if (responseData.id != null && !responseData.id.Equals(""))
        {
            // Shared successfully
            MessageBox.Show("Message Posted!");
        }
        else if (responseData.error != null && responseData.error.code == 190)
        {
            if (responseData.error.error_subcode == 463)
            {
                // need to get new token
                FacebookClient.Instance.ExchangeAccessToken(new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(ExchangeAccessTokenCompleted));
            }
            else
            {
                // need to clear the Access Token
                FacebookClient.Instance.AccessToken = "";
                SetLoggedInState(false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Error
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this error...

Comment: I think their API has some rules, like same contents of a post cannot be posted again(atleast for a while).

Comment: @RaghavMac but I checked in burrp! android app . same content post again and again.

Comment: That's weird. Then better, you just mail them about this issue. Because I read something about fb post duplication not allowed.